# How to wait for DOM operation completion?

Tags: dom, vb6, browser

I have to maintain a part of an old Windows VB6 project (so, don't tell me to migrate-it to VB.NET). This program embeds the well known webbrowser control (IE) in which it loads local HTML files (containing different stats, but doesn't matter). Knowing we don't want any scroll bar in the web browser view (even if HTML page is longer than the webbrowser window, we just need to see what it's on top), we manage DOM on DocumentComplete event like this :

```
Private Sub wb_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
 wb.Document.documentElement.Style.overflow = "hidden"
 ProcessWithDStats
End Sub
```

All sounds right and the vertical scrollbar well disappear, but now, I need to add some stuff in the ProcessWithDStats sub (a big sub calling a lot of functions) which need to be sure the previous DOM operation is totally completed (I mean : scrollbar hidden and it's content re-justified accordingly to this new width w/o scrollbar).

So, how to do ?

At this time, ProcessWithDStats is executed before DOM management really finish to be rendered !

Until now, here are my attempts :

- I've tried to add a scrollbar testing (comparing doc width and browser client area one) between the two lines, but it doesn't work : test is OK, but reflow of text (because of this change of width when scrollbar disappear) has not enough time for being applied before ProcessWithDStats is engaged.
- I've tried to Sleep(), but it locks entire program (webbrowser rendering included)

Well is there a way to wait for real application of the given DOM management in this WebBrowser control ?

I mean something like :

```
Do
 Doevents
Loop Until [DOM modification and rendering completed]
```

Comment: Does your document use frames? If so, the control might fire multiple DocumentComplete events and you would need to look at the pDisp parameter to tell if it is the top level document. If (pDisp Is WebBrowser1.Object) Then ...

Comment: Unfortunately, no, Beaner : there's not any frame or iframe. But since my question I've had an idea that I've tried and which seems to work (but is not very smart, I think ; so, a solution awaiting a real and smart one). Just between the two lines, I add a dummy DOM operation which does nothing but has the advantage to be synchronous to the previous "overflow hidden" one : 

    doc.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 1
    doc.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, -1 

So, when time comes to engage ProcessWithDStats, reflow has been done. What do you think about that ? Do you have a better way in mind ?

Comment: It sounds like you have as good a work around as any.

Comment: :o) However, if I find a better way a day or another, I'll be back to tell you here...

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this... at the very least.

```
Do
 Sleep 100
 Doevents
Loop Until wb.Busy = False And wb.ReadyState = 4
```

On your version the .Busy may be called .IsBusy but are the same thing.

Also, there are additional things you should do if you want to truely know if a browser is done loading, read some of my previous answers if you want to know more, or need more accuracy than the above, but what i have included for you is for sure a much better solution than you currently have. Let me know if you need it to work on 100% of websites or just a select few, if a select few than this simple method may be enough.

Let me know hwo it goes anyway, cheers.